# Dynamic localhost URL in redirect URI

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, google-directory-api

I'm running the Directory API https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/quickstart/python in Google Colab. To use the API I need to authorize an account and it prompts me to login using my Google Workspace admin account.
[[image]

I add the localhost to my redirectURI in Google Cloud Console, and then I get a redirection to http://localhost:45623/?state='SOMEID'&code='SOMEOTHERLETTERS'&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user

and I get stuck. I can't add colab.research.google.com because that's not the redirect URI Google is detecting.

My file is stuck here in Please visit this URL to authorize this application: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=...... [image]

Another situation I experienced is that once I refresh my page, the localhost port will change and I have to add a new one.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: always put code, data and full error message as text (not screenshot, not link) in question (not in comment).  It will be more readable and more people will see it - so more people can help you.

Comment: the source code is the quickstart.py that's on the website I pasted [https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/quickstart/python] and behavior is reproducible even in Pycharm because the localhost changes to a different one everytime I run the code. I won't post the full error message, because it contains the client ID and client secret.